# add items to arrayList property in Runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

i just want to add items to ArrayList property in Runtime using Reflection, 
is this possible?
it is my first time to ask on forums so I hope my question is clear and seems serious..

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection? Why can't you do `ArrayList.Insert()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` implements `IList`, so all you have to do is to get ahold of an appropriate `PropertyInfo` object (`foo.GetType().GetProperty("...")`), get it's value (`propertyInfo.GetValue(foo, null)`), cast it to `IList` and `Add()` whatever you want.

Comment: Do we really need to casting here?